# MS Access table not refreshing correctly after inserting with c# ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I'm having an strange behaviour when inserting records in an empty MS Access table using an external c# application

My process is:

1. From inside Access I execute the c# console application using a WshShell object, with 'waitOnReturn', so access waits until shell ends.
2. The c# just connects to the database, and executes a non query oledbCommand
3. When Access resumes after shell ends, I try to read the new records, but get an error: no records!. But, If I manually open the updated table, the records are there!

So, the problem is that the table does not update after inserting

This is my code in Access

```vb
Dim wsh As Object
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean
Dim errorCode As Integer

Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
waitOnReturn = True
errorCode = wsh.Run("UpdateTable.exe", vbMaximizedFocus, waitOnReturn)

If errorCode <> 0 Then GoTo Error:

Dim dbf As DAO.Database
Dim UpdatedTable As DAO.Recordset

Set dbf = CurrentDb
Set UpdatedTable = dbf.OpenRecordset("MyTable", dbOpenTable)
UpdatedTable.MoveFirst   'ERROR! No records found
```

But records have been inserted! They are there!. In fact, when I get the error, Access stops and enter in debug mode. At this moment I manually open "MyTable" and I see the data. Then, I close the table, and resume (continue) the Access code execution, and now the records are found and code runs smooth.

The c# code for inserting records (in this example, only one record) is this:

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;data source=" + pathToMyDB;
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable ([Field1], [Field2])" + " VALUES (@Param1, @Param2)";
    command.Parameters.Add("@Param1", OleDbType.WChar, 35);
    command.Parameters.Add("@Param2", OleDbType.Date);
    command.Parameters["@Param1"].Value = "my string";
    command.Parameters["@Param2"].Value = DateTime.Now;
    int insertedRowsCount = 0;
    using (OleDbTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        command.Transaction = transaction;
        try
        {
            insertedRowsCount = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException queryExecutionException)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            ProcessQueryExecutionExceptions(queryExecutionException);
        }
        if (insertedRowsCount == 1)
        {
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        else
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
    command.Parameters.Clear();
    connection.Close();
}
```

In Access, what could be the problem? Is there a way to force access to refresh or update the table before reading it? I have tried to close and reopen table before movefirst, inserted `DoEvents` after shell execution... Nothing works :(

In c#, is something wrong with the code? Should I have to change something in the connection string, or the command, or the transaction to force the update of the table?

Comment: Maybe try a dbf.TableDefs.Refresh just after your Set dbf = ...but not sure...

Comment: The line: "INSERT INTO MyTable ([Field1], [Field2])" + " VALUES (@Param1, @Param2)"; is essentially the same as: "INSERT INTO MyTable ([Field1], [Field2]) VALUES (@Param1, @Param2)"; Are you sure that syntax is correct? Best regards,

Comment: Why are you using Transaction just for a single insert command? And what is the accurate timing of the two operations - one in C# and another from within the Access? Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not really a c# code issue.  It is simply that the Access session is not yet aware of the new record which was added by an external process.  The same thing can happen with an `INSERT` from *any* external process.  I reproduced the problem with a VBScript file substituted for `UpdateTable.exe`

This Access VBA code triggers error 3021, *"No current record"* at `UpdatedTable.MoveFirst` ...

```vb
Dim dbf As DAO.Database
Dim UpdatedTable As DAO.Recordset
Dim wsh As Object
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean
Dim errorCode As Integer

Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
waitOnReturn = True
errorCode = wsh.Run("C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe C:\share\Access\vbscript\AdoInsert.vbs", vbMaximizedFocus, waitOnReturn)

'CreateObject("JRO.JetEngine").RefreshCache CurrentProject.Connection
Set dbf = CurrentDb
Set UpdatedTable = dbf.OpenRecordset("tblKaikus", dbOpenTable)
UpdatedTable.MoveFirst ' without RefreshCache -> ERROR 3021, "No current record."
```

Enabling the `CreateObject("JRO.JetEngine").RefreshCache` line makes the newly added record immediately available in the current Access session, so the recordset `MoveFirst` method does not trigger an error.

Comment: Whoa! I forgot to mark yor perfect solution as an answer... Sorry :(